# mysql get 4th, 5th, 6th, 7th result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, limit

Im making a query to the database where on the first query I limit the results to 4 by doing :

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members limit 4");
```

This gets me my first 4 entries in the DB and On my next query I want to get the next four what kind of approach should I take?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members limit 4 count= 5");
```

Comment: Just to be clear. The ***next four queries*** are not the 4th, 5th, 6th, and 7th results. It's the indexes 4, 5, 6, and 7 or the 5th, 6th, 7th, and 8th results. SQL is zero based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LIMIT can take two arguments:

> LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]

In your case you would do:

```
SELECT * FROM members limit 4,4;
```

But to do this consistently, you really should use some sort of ORDER BY, otherwise you are not assured to get consistent results.

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d7eff/2)</kbd>

Comment: Your SQL query returns the 5th, 6th, 7th, and 8th values. The OP wants the 4th, 5th, 6th, and 7th values. It should be `limit 3,4;`

Comment: He says: "This gets me my first 4 entries in the DB and On my next query I want to get the next four what kind of approach should I take?". Don't think that 3,4 would do that.

Comment: Ah, yes I see where the OP has that noted. Fair enough. +1 Sorry I was going by the title. It seems the OP is a little confused...

Comment: yes. i agree that the title isn't consistent with the content.

Answer (score 3):

You're close:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members limit 3,4");
```

This tells MySQL to start returning rows at the fourth row (remember, mysql starts counting at zero so 0 is the first row and 3 is the fourth row) and return four rows total.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. If he does LIMIT 4, it's the same as doing LIMIT 0,4. Which means that when he wants to get the next 4, you would do LIMIT 4,4.

Answer (score 2):

SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 3, 4;